how to close the previous accordions when scrolling the page and reach to new accordion?
I am using accordion material-mui. at first all of accordions are opened. when I scroll the page and I reach to the second accordion, I want to close the first accordion and when I reach to the third accordion , I want to close the previous ones and so on. the log of  ref.current.offsetTop is always bigger than newScrollYPosition and when I change the if to > and it removes accordions[0].id but it did not close the accordion.  How can I do that?
my simple code is in the below link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nzp98t?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2FApp.css&terminal=dev
import { Accordion as MuiAccordion } from '@mui/material'

    export const Accordion = ({
  className,
  accordions,
  scrollableContainerRef,
}: AccordionProps) => {
  const [expandedIds, setExpandedIds] = useState<string[]>(
    accordions.map(({ id }) => id)
  )
  const accordionRefs = useRef<(React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null)[]>(
    accordions.map(() => React.createRef())
  )

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const newScrollYPosition = scrollableContainerRef.current?.scrollTop || 0

    accordionRefs.current.forEach((ref) => {
      if (ref.current) {
        if (ref.current.offsetTop < newScrollYPosition) {
          setExpandedIds((prevExpandedIds) =>
            prevExpandedIds.filter((id) => id !== accordions[0].id)
          )
        }
      }
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollableContainerRef.current) {
      scrollableContainerRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
    return () => {
      if (scrollableContainerRef.current) {
        scrollableContainerRef.current.removeEventListener(
          'scroll',
          handleScroll
        )
      }
    }
  }, [scrollableContainerRef])

  const accordionsList = useMemo(() => {
    return accordions.map(({ id, title, content, disabled }, index) => (
      <MuiAccordion
        key={id}
        disabled={disabled}
        defaultExpanded={expandedIds.includes(id)}
        ref={accordionRefs.current[index]}
      >
        <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} id={id}>
          {title}
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>{content}</AccordionDetails>
      </MuiAccordion>
    ))
  }, [accordions, expandedIds])

  return (
    <div className={classNames('accordion', className)}>{accordionsList}</div>
  )
}


Caution when you are below the accordion to be closed: when closing, it will change the relative scroll position, so you would need to simulateneously scroll back the visitor's view. Worst case you may end up jumping from accordions to accordions...

export const Accordion = ({ className, accordions }: AccordionProps) => {

  const accordionRefs = useRef<(React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null)[]>(
    accordions.map(() => React.createRef())
  )
  const scrollableContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  const [expandedIds, setExpandedIds] = useState<string[]>(
    accordions.map(({ id }) => id)
  )

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const newScrollYPosition = scrollableContainerRef.current?.scrollTop || 0

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            const accordionId = entry.target.getAttribute('data-id')
            if (
              accordionId &&
              newScrollYPosition > entry.boundingClientRect.top
            ) {
              setExpandedIds((prevExpandedIds) =>
                prevExpandedIds.filter(
                  (expandedId) => expandedId !== accordionId
                )
              )
            }
          }
        })
      },
      {
        threshold: 0.5,
        root: document.querySelector('.accordion'),
      }
    )
    accordionRefs.current.forEach((ref, index) => {
      if (ref && ref.current) {
        observer.observe(ref.current)
        ref.current.setAttribute('data-id', accordions[index].id) // Add a unique identifier to each accordion
      }
    })

    return () => observer.disconnect()
  }
  //
  const onChange = (id: string) => {
    setExpandedIds((prevIds) => {
      const isExpanded = prevIds.includes(id)
      return isExpanded
        ? prevIds.filter((expandedId) => expandedId !== id)
        : [...prevIds, id]
    })
  }

  const accordionsList = useMemo(() => {
    return accordions.map(({ id, title, content, disabled }, index) => (
      <MuiAccordion
        key={id}
        disabled={disabled}
        expanded={expandedIds.includes(id)}
        ref={accordionRefs.current[index]}
        onChange={() => onChange(id)}
      >
        <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} id={id}>
          {title}
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>{content}</AccordionDetails>
      </MuiAccordion>
    ))
  }, [accordions, expandedIds])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollableContainerRef.current) {
      scrollableContainerRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
    return () => {
      if (scrollableContainerRef.current) {
        scrollableContainerRef.current.removeEventListener(
          'scroll',
          handleScroll
        )
      }
    }
  }, [scrollableContainerRef])

  return (
    <div
      className={classNames('accordion', className)}
      ref={scrollableContainerRef}
    >
      {accordionsList}
    </div>
  )
}


defaultExpanded worked at the first render. use expanded instead.
codes like
import { Accordion as MuiAccordion } from '@mui/material'

export const Accordion = ({ accordions }: AccordionProps) => {
  const [expandedIds, setExpandedIds] = useState<string[]>(
    accordions.map(({ id }) => id)
  );


 useEffect(() => {
     document.body.addEventListenr('scroll', () => {
         if ( reach accordion ) {
            setExpandedIds([...])
         }
     })
 }, [])

 return (
    <div className="accordion">
      {accordions.map(({ id, title, content, disabled }) => (
        <MuiAccordion
          key={id}
          disabled={disabled}
          expanded={expandedIds.includes(id)}
        >
          <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} id={id}>
            {title}
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>{content}</AccordionDetails>
        </MuiAccordion>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


Thanks but I know that should I use scroll . my problem is how I detect to reach the accordion ?

you need  IntersectionObserver
